# Do server-sent events only handle strings?

Tags: javascript, php, json, server-sent-events

I'm using SSE to stream content without the need of refreshing the webpage. Basically my main procedure is the following:

```
$query = "SELECT something something";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
// ^this will return multiple rows eventually

$content= array();
while($inside= $result->fetch_assoc()){     

        array_push($content,$inside);

        }

//$content is now an array with multiple rows, all inserted corrected by debug

$final = json_encode($content);
//^ the json is encoded as supposed [{"something":"something"},{"another":...}]

echo "data: {$final}";
//^ which I then receive with javascript (or at least I want to).
flush();
```

The thing is that nothing is received in javascript. No errors, no console.logs, nothing at all. I've tried to work around the json in javascript but it just feels *ghastly* (no json there at all). Is this impossible to do? How should do it then if so? (**I have tested with time() and the javascript is working completely fine dumping the data**)

---

**EDIT** : JAVASCRIPT

```
var source=new EventSource("test.php");
    console.log("1");
    source.onmessage=function(event)
      {
            console.log("inside .onmessage !!!");
            var data = event.data;
            //data.forEach(function(each){
            //  console.log(each);
            //});
                //var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log(data);
      };
```

Commented parts are related to my problem. All other lines were to debug with the time() function.

Comment: Can you post the javascript as well?

Comment: Remember you have to parse the JSON using JSON.parse(string). More info over at MDN; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Comment: @SimonPlus Of course :) I also tried that but the problem is that no variable is received at all. It doesn't even go inside source.onmessage and I can only suppose that's related to the content being json. When it was a string it entered just fine...

Comment: Do you really need ```EventSource```? It's mainly used for server-side events. Maybe a [```XMLHttpRequest```](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) is what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you have forgotten the [stream format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#Event_stream_format):

> Each message is separated by a pair of newline characters.

Try

```
echo "data: {$final}\n\n";
```

Comment: Oh ffs, didn't even notice I erased that off xD thank you very much!